# Is there a way to change the color of the paint for a Java Canvas GUI?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, canvas, draw

I have a program that allows you to draw on a canvas in a GUI, and I have set the color to black. Is there a way that I could make it so if for  example, I press 2 and the color changes to blue, or 3 and it changes to green? Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Draw extends Canvas {
  int x, y;
  Color color;

  public static void main( String[] args ) {
     JFrame draw = new JFrame("Use the arrow keys to draw!");
     draw.setSize(1020, 764);
     draw.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
     draw.add( new Draw() );
     draw.setVisible(true);
 }

 public Draw() {
    enableEvents(java.awt.AWTEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK);
    requestFocus();
    x = 500;
    y = 500;
    color = Color.black;
 }

 public void paint( Graphics g ) {
    g.setColor(color);
    g.fillOval(x, y, 15, 15);
 }

 public void update( Graphics g ) {
    paint(g);
 }

 public void processKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
   // this method automatically gets called when you press a key
   if ( e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED ) {
      if ( e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP ) 
         y -= 10; 
      if ( e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN )
         y += 10;
      if ( e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT ) 
         x -= 10;
      if ( e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT )
         x += 10;
  

    

   repaint();
  }
 }

 public boolean isFocusable()
 {
  return true;
 }
}
```

Comment: `if ( e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_2){
      this.color = Color.BLUE;
  }`

Comment: Generally, there is no reason to mix an AWT `Canvas` with a Swing GUI. To create a custom component, just extend `JComponent` and override `paintComponent` instead of `paint` and `update`. That will simplify your code and eliminate problems of mixing heavyweight and lightweight components you’re not even aware of.